# Query to find by calculated date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I would like to create a query in mongoose to achieve this functionality:

Mongoose models:

```
Planted_crop: owner: id, date_planted: Date, crop: id, quantity: Number
Crop: name: String, water_consumption: Number, grow_time: Number (means hours)
```

And now I would like to get all planted crops that aren't fully grown yet, In semi code this would be it:

```
if (plantedCrop.date_planted < plantedCrop.date_planted + plantedCrop.crop.grow_time) {
    // this crop should be selected
}
```

And now I need to translate this to mongodb:

```
var PlantedCrop = mongoose.model("planted_crop");
PlantedCrop.find({ 
    date_planted: { 
        $lt: {
            date_planted + crop.grow_time * 3600
        }
    }
}).populate("crop").exec(function(err, crops) {
    // calculate water consumption
    var consumption = 0, planted;
    for (var i = 0; i < crops.length; i++) {
        planted = crops[i];
        consumption += planted.crop.water_consumption * planted.quantity;
    }
    console.log("Water consumption of planted crops is " + consumption + " liters.
});
```

I am stuck at creating such query, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do this, and therefore the best part of an answer will explain why you don't want this approach. Instead you should calculate the time a grop will be grown at the time of creation, and this is really just maintaining an extra field as in ( just showing the required fields ):

```
var date = new Date();

PlantedCrop.create({
    "owner": ownerId,
    "crop": cropId,
    "date"_planted": date,
    "grow_time": ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ) * 2, // "milliseconds" for two hours
    "ready_time": new Date( date.valueOf() + ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ) * 2)
});
```

Then finding if that crop is not currently "fully grown" from the current time is as simple as:

```
PlantedCrop.find({ "ready_time": { "$gte": new Date() } },function(err,crops) {

});
```

And if you wanted things that are "ready" one hour from the current date then you just do:

```
PlantedCrop.find({ 
   "ready_time": { 
       "$gte": new Date( Date.now + ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ) )
   } 
},function(err,crops) {

});
```

That is functionally simple and not confusing as all of the information is recorded when written and you simply look it up to set if it is grown yet.

The "danger" with thinking about this in terms of calculation is that you start moving towards using a [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) type of query with JavaScript evaluation of the fields:

```
PlantedCrop.find({
    "$where": function() {
        return this.date_planted.valueOf() + grow_time > Date.now;
    }
},function(err,crops) {

});
```

And this is very **bad** as such a test cannot use an index for the search and will "brute force" try to match every document in the collection.

That is what you want to avoid and what you want to keep clean in the processing logic, but the other alternative is just work the math on the client when creating the request. Simply work backwards and check that the crop was planted "less than one hour" ago, and the grow time is in fact greater:

```
PlantedCrop.find({ 
   "date_planed": { 
       "$lte": new Date( Date.now - ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ) )
   },
   "grow_time": { "$gte": ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ) }
},function(err,crops) {

});
```

And that will find you all crops "not fully grown" within the timeframe that you ask.

But as to the original point, it just looks clunky and ugly, and is simply fixed by just storing the final calculated date and querying for that alone instead.

Also please make sure that all this data is in the one collection, just as suggested at the begining. You cannot reference values from populated items in such a query as that is called a "join", which MongoDB does not do. Population merely "prettfies" object references by performing another query to replace those object references with whole objects, "after" initial queries are done.